How is SER secured within a "sleeve"?
I will be mounting a new meter/main on the outside wall of my house as part of a heavy-up.  It will receive 3x4/0 SEU, and I will have 3x4/0+2/0 SER feeding through to my internal subpanel, where most of the power distribution for my house will happen.
Due to the exact positioning, the feedthrough cable needs to exit the back of the meter/main (toward the bottom), and penetrate the house.  My plan is to drill a 2.5" hole through my brick and use some sort of construction adhesive to lock a 2" conduit nipple (6" long or so) in place.  The meter/main end of the nipple will have a locknut, then pass through the box, then have a locknut + bushing.
I'm planning on making this nipple a sleeve for cable protection, not a raceway.  My reasoning here is due to (1) conduit fill and (2) the need to run a grounding electrode conductor back through this sleeve to bond in the meter/main.
How should I handle the other end (that opens into the basement, inside the house)?  One option is just to leave it open - this will be easiest for getting the SER and grounding electric conductor through.  I'm not sure if this is satisfactory for securing the SER though: after it exits the sleeve, it'll travel a foot or two before going through a clamp into the top of my subpanel.
Which options are acceptable per code?

Leave the inside end of the sleeve bare
Use a coupler + cable clamp on the inside end of the sleeve (how do I get the grounding electrode conductor through?)
Use a locknut + bushing on the inside end of the sleeve for cable protection
Use conduit all the way to the subpanel (now I have to worry about conduit fill?)
Another option that is none of the above?

Is there perhaps a way to secure it inside the meter/main that would satisfy code?

For anybody following up on this down the road, my sleeve is short enough that I can use a clamp to secure the cable to some framing once the SER exits and still be within 12" of the meter/main.  If that was not the case, I would have to get creative (inside-facing tonic clamp or something).  I am also using my stated option #3.
